# Sqlite Python display table at once

Tags: python, sqlite

I've made a  small database program in Python using SQLite. My goal is to display all my entries that are in my table. I'm able to make that happen, but I have to hit Enter each time.

```
elif selection == '2': 
  print "Opened database successfully \n"
  cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM DATABASE")
  all = cursor.fetchall()
  for row in all:
    print "ID = ", row[0], "NAME = ", row[1],  "CHECKED IN = ",  row[2], "\n"
    raw_input()
```

Is there a way I can display them all at once?

I have tired to remove the `raw_input` but all that does is goes back to my menu.

Comment: Put `raw_input()` outside your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it stops is because you have `raw_input()` in your loop; you can move it out of your loop:

```
elif selection == '2': 
   print "Opened database successfully \n"
   cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM DATABASE")
   all = cursor.fetchall()
   for row in all:
      print "ID = ", row[0], "NAME = ", row[1],  "CHECKED IN = ",  row[2], "\n"
   raw_input()
```

Also, please pay attention to indenting in Python it is critical.

Comment: I should have known it was something so simple. That's why an extra set of eyes are good